# Java equivalent of perror in C

Tags: java, c, error-handling

I hope to execute a bash script and obtain normal output or error message. I know for C we have `erron` or `perror` to get the number of exit code and the corresponding message. Whether or not there is an equivalent for Java. If not, how could we achieve the same task as in C?

Answer (score 1):

If you start your process like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command>");
```

The the error code is return like this:

```
int error_code = p.waitFor();
```

Comment: thanks. I know Runtime and I use ProcessBuilder.start() then Process.exitCode() to obtain the exit code. But I've no idea how to get the error message corresponding to my exit code.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing things.

The exit status from a *process*, out to bash, Java or whatever environment started it, is *not* the same thing as the values of `errno`, that can be printed by [`perror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror). The latter are errors for individual system calls, which are clearly at a much lower level.

The exit status of a process can be whatever, there's no standard for that since it's usually just pass/fail, the detailed level is typically coverered by the program itself.

See, for instance, [the exit status of GNU `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Exit-Status):

> Normally, the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise. But the exit status is 2 if an error occurred [...].

That's very high-level, and doesn't tell you *what* error occured inside `grep`, just that overall, it failed.

Comment: thank you. i understand what you said. what I need to do is to get exit value return by process, whether succeed or fail. so I would get number from 0 to 255 theorically. and I also hope to find the error message associate with the number. for example, when I do "Kill -9 20145", then "echo $?" I would get 137(128+9), and when I do "jqzioejg" I will get 127 and message of "command not found".